# Bash How To Start Iterating At Specific String Matching Condition In List

Tags: bash

I can't seem to find this exact case even though it seems like probably there is an answer for it.  Here is what I am trying to do:

I have a list of 150 Strings sorted alphabetically.  Currently I am iterating through them one by one and then prompting the User to confirm they want to proceed:

```
mylist="$(terraform workspace list | sed 's/*//g')"  #gets list of 150 strings sorted alphabetically
for v in $mylist
do
    echo "$v"
    read -p "Do you wish to take this Terraform related action" (Y/N)?" yn

    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) echo "Taking the terraform related action ";
                ##take action
                ;;
        [Nn]* ) echo "Not taking an action.";
                continue;;
done
```

This works fine, but the issue is if the user goes through a subset of the list and then exits the script, they need to start again at the beginning when they rerun it.  So, I want them to be able to enter the first couple of characters that they want to start iterating from.

```
function get_user_args() {
  while getopts ":s:" opt; do
    case ${opt} in
      s )
        start_characters=$OPTARG
        ;;
...
```

And so if the user enters `-s de` I want to iterate through the list of strings starting with the first one that begins with `de`.  How can I do this?

Comment: If looping is not an issue then simply use an flag. Just loop through the list and don't prompt for input. Set the flag once the list item matches the passed arg value. Once the flag is set, start prompting. But if saving the state of the previous sessions inputs is required, that is a different issue.

Comment: If you're using `getopts` in a function, do `'local OPTIND OPTARG; while getopts ...`

Comment: What is the advantage to doing that?  The pattern I normally follow is to have the last line effectively return `shift $((OPTIND -1))`.  What problems could that cause that setting local variables would fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, [don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001): with bash use `mapfile`

```sh
mapfile -t mylist < <(terraform workspace list | sed 's/*//g')
```

Then, iterate over that array with

```sh
for v in "${mylist[@]}"; do #...
```

Now, to your question, you can compare the current $v to the $start_characters lexically:

```sh
for v in "${mylist[@]}"; do 
    if [[ "$v" < "$start_characters" ]]; then
        continue
    fi
    # or as a one-liner
    [[ "$v" < "$start_characters" ]] && continue
```

Comment: You might want to set a default in case they don't give you anything - something like `[[ "$v" < "${start_characters:-zzz}" ]]` though the locale and encoding might matter more than a little...

Comment: Well, more like `${start_characters:=A}` but your point is good.

Comment: That is a good point.  I am setting it in a function called `defaults_and_checks()` and if `start_characters` is empty then I set it to "A".  I am sharing that only because I am not sure if this is a proper bash way to do it

Comment: Ok this worked great, so I am going to accept the answer.  The only thing to add is for some reason the mapfile command added 2 leading whitespaces to each term, and so I had to remove the whitespace like this in my loop `v=$(echo "$v" | xargs)`

Comment: Those spaces are there because they are in the input. You can strip the leading whitespace with just bash: first `shopt -s extglob` to turn on [extended patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching), then `v=${v##+([[:blank:]])}` will strip off all leading blanks (horizontal whitespace)

Comment: Nice that worked very well.  Certainly this question has opened my eyes to more things I can do in bash than the patterns I've followed over the past couple years.  Thanks for your help!